# How to remove characters in a string that matches a RegEx while preserving spaces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to remove characters from a string so that it will match this RegEx: `^[-a-zA-Z0-9._:,]+$`. For example:

`const input = "test // hello"`. The expected output would be "test hello". I tried the following:

```
input.replace(/^[-a-zA-Z0-9._:,]+$/g, "")
```

But this does not seem to work

Comment: add `\s` to the regex? - actually your regex is incorrect because it looks for the whole string `^` thru to `$`

Comment: It's not just the whitespace that's not working. Currently no characters are removed. I asked this question because I'm not familiar with Regex but still tried something

Comment: that's because your regex will only match a whole string (from beginning to end) - you want to match parts of the string, so remove the `^` and `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example output `"hello world"` that you give does *not* match your regex, because the regex does not allow spaces. Assuming you want to keep spaces, use

```js
input.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9._:, ]/g, "")
```

The negation character `^` must be inside the `[...]`. The `+` is not needed, because `/g` already ensures that all matching characters are replaced (that is, removed).

If you also want to condense consecutive spaces into a single space (as implied by your example), use

```js
input.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9._:, ]/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the following canonical approach:

```js
var input = "test // hello";
var output = input.replace(/\s*[^-a-zA-Z0-9._:, ]+\s*/g, " ").trim()
console.log(output);
```

The logic here is to target all unwanted characters *and* their surrounding whitespace.  We replace with just a single space.  Then we do a trim at the end in case there might be an extra leading/trailing space.